# Return the number of bits which are set to 1 inside a variable representation

Tags: c, variables, integer, 8-bit

Let's suppose I have an unsigned integer number represented in an 8bit variable.
I want to write a function that returns the number of bits which are set to 1 inside the variable representation.
For example the function should return 1 if the number is 1 and 2 if the number is.. let's say 5.
How can I do this? I looked on this website to other questions but didn't find a clear answer for my question, or a similar question.

Thanks in advance.

Update:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int NumberOfSetBits(int i)
{
i = i - ((i >> 1) & 0x55555555);
  i = (i & 0x33333333) + ((i >> 2) & 0x33333333);
 return (((i + (i >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F) * 0x01010101) >> 24;
}

int main(){
printf("%d\n",NumberOfSetBits(4));
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think 4 would have 2 bits set to 1?

Comment: The operation is sometimes called "sideways addition" or "popcount".  There are intrinsics for this and some well-known algorithms.

Comment: AKA finding the Hamming weight.

Comment: Exactly, it's the Hamming weight. I didn't knew at first how it's called.

Comment: @user2357112 I edited, I wanted to write 5. Because 5 is 0101

Comment: Done, I edited my answer. For 4 the result will be 2, and for 5 the result will be 2..

Comment: no need to know about Hamming weight. You just need to google for "get number of set bits" to get the results immediately

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21051663/1566187 seems to be of interest I think. It's taken from K&R - a great book still after so many years. I recommend you learn C with this book too.